# What happens to my demo game data if I buy it on different PSN account?

Tags: ps4, psn

I have 2 different accounts from different countries on my PS4.

I have downloaded the demo of *Watch Dogs 2* on ACCOUNT1 and played it. Now, I want to buy it from the PlayStation Store on ACCOUNT2 on the same console. If I buy it, will I lose my game data from the demo that I played on a different account?

In short, I want to buy the game with ACCOUNT2, but I already have the demo version installed under ACCOUNT1. I don't want to start from the beginning after I purchase the game. Will this be the case? I also wonder if it will be a problem because the two accounts are from different countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As save data does not transfer across accounts, there would be no consequences to purchasing the game on your second account if the demo was played on your first account.

However, any bonuses that would have come from having played the demo on your first account will not be granted to you on your second account. The demo would need to have been played on the same account you're using the purchase the game. If there are no rewards for playing the demo, then it doesn't matter which account you buy the game on, as the demo has no effect on the game.

Additionally, unless your second account has that PS4 console listed as its primary console, your first account wouldn't even have access to the game if you purchased it with your second account.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I couldn't understand one point. There is no 'reward' on demo game. I just played half hour and achieved some of the missions. Now If I buy it on a different account, will I continue from the same checkpoint? Or will I start from the beginning? And will I download the game again, or it will just 'unlock' the demo game?

Comment: @Eray I'm not sure how this particular game works, but no game will have multiple accounts share save data

Comment: So it means 99% I will start from the beginning and this answer is enough for me. Thank you again.